# change from href target="_blank" to iframe with radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a page with a list of links (or buttons or pictures doesn't matter), so that when the user clicks the button / link, depending on the radio selection, the link  will be opened either in an iframe on the same page or open a new window with target="_blank". Is it possible?

I thought maybe to use a form like this:

```
<html>    
 <head><title>Rec. Links</title></head>     
<body>    
<form method="get" action="?">         
<imput type="radio" value="new" name="group1"/>    
<input type="radio" value="iframe"name="group1"/>    
</form>    
<a href="..."/>    
<a href="..."/>    
<a href="..."/>    
...    
<a href="..."/>    
</body>    
</html>
```

But where can I send the selection? Can I send it to same page itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to add a click handler on each of your radio buttons, e.g.

```
... onclick="updateTargets('iframe');" />
... onclick="updateTargets('_blank');" />
```

Create a function that will change the target of every anchor:

```
function updateTargets(newTarget)
{
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for (var i = 0, item; item = anchors[i]; ++i) {
        item.target = newTarget;
    }
}
```

Comment: Will work, but need to validate if `newTarget` is a accepted value. The OP had given "new" as a `target` value which is not correct.

Comment: @Pushpesh I'm already using correct values in the `onclick` handler code.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery something like this may start you off - basically you bind to the radio groups change event and then change all target attributes of anchors depending on the value selected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('input:radio[name=group1]').change(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(value == "iframe") {
                $('a').attr('target', '');
        } else {
                $('a').attr('target', '_blank');
        }
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="get" action="?">
<input type="radio" value="new" name="group1" />
<input type="radio" value="iframe"name="group1"/>
</form>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Jello</a>
</body>
</html>
```